# How to save subviews using local data - swift

Tags: swift

I have successfully built an image editor as you see in the pic. I would like to let users save the work as an open-source project so they can open it again to edit. I'm not really sure how to do it. any ideas? I'm thinking if I can save the whole UIViewController with subviews in array locally. can I use `NSKeyedUnarchiver` to do that and how?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had some good experience using [`NSUserActivity`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsuseractivity) for sharing tasks between various Apple devices. It makes sense, you're going to restart the same activity even if it's the same user on same device and it makes sharing your work a doddle between all Apple devices as a bonus.

However I'm not sure how well it allows to embed binaries like your images. But you'll have the same problem using `NSKeyedArchiver`.